# Passing multiple lines of input for SageMaker prediction

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I have built a SageMaker pipeline which uses a combination of Custom Transformer (using SKLearn Transformer and an XGBoost model). A sample pipeline is shown below:

```
from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker.pipeline import PipelineModel
import boto3
from time import gmtime, strftime

timestamp_prefix = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

scikit_learn_inferencee_model = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model()
xg_model = xg_estimator.create_model()

model_name = 'inference-pipeline-' + timestamp_prefix
endpoint_name = 'inference-pipeline-ep-' + timestamp_prefix
sm_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, 
    role=role, 
    models=[
        scikit_learn_inference_model, 
        xg_model])

sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

Tbe sklearn preprocessor takes 100 rows of input and generates a single line that is passed as input to the XGBoost model for prediction. So for every 100 rows of input, I get only one prediction.

However, all the examples for SageMaker prediction point to only one row of input as follows:

```
from sagemaker.predictor import json_serializer, csv_serializer, json_deserializer, RealTimePredictor
from sagemaker.content_types import CONTENT_TYPE_CSV, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON

payload = 'M, 0.44, 0.365, 0.125, 0.516, 0.2155, 0.114, 0.155'
actual_rings = 10

predictor = RealTimePredictor(
    endpoint=endpoint_name,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    serializer=csv_serializer,
    content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_CSV,
    accept=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)

print(predictor.predict(payload))
```

How can I pass multiple of rows of input to a SageMaker endpoint and get 1 prediction out?

Thank you.

Comment: doing some searching for the same scenario, I landed here how. were you able find a solution for your question. I am also wondering, if say the one input can be in multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the documentation for SageMaker Batch Transform: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#sagemaker-batch-transform

You'll need to use a `Transformer`: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/transformer.html#sagemaker.transformer.Transformer